# Pull first instance of input and add id via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have to add an id to an element. An engine generates the HTML... I have no access to it. It generates random IDs as such:

```
<input id="5352Adkdie4929888a">
```

I want to grab the first instance of "`<input id=`" and replace the ID it has with
the ID it has + DatePicker.

Example:

```
<input id="5352Adkdie4929888a DatePicker">
```

How would I go about doing this?

My code so far:

```
function addID(){
    var html= document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    var start= '<input id="';
    var end= '"'
    var htmlIWant=html.substring(html.indexOf(start) + start.length), html.indexOf(end)-1 + 'DatePicker';
}
```

Am I on the right track? How do I actually replace the HTML? Thanks!

Comment: no jquery in this OP

Comment: removed.. it was a suggested tag... sorry

Comment: Every input tag will have an `ID` or some of them can be without `ID` ?

Comment: There are multiple inputs that have IDs... I want the first instance.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option for you?

Comment: I mean every input must have an `ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure `javascript` solution as per your requirements.

Assuming that your page will have many `input` tags and some of them will be without `ID` attribute below is a solution you can try.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
   if (elements[i].type == "text" && elements[i].hasAttribute("id"))
    {
       var id = elements[i].getAttribute("id");
       elements[i].setAttribute("id", id + "10");
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the first input inside the element using

```
$('input:first-child').attr('id','whateverIdName');
```

Comment: I would upvote this if you had provided a demo to demonstrate your code works. *Just press Ctrl+M and add your code in the appropriate boxes.*

Answer (score 1):

If you have to catch first input box that has id attribute, you should do :

```js
$("input[id]")[0]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```